# MongoDB regenerate .ns file

Tags: mongodb, backup, recovery

We accidentally deleted mongo db .ns file from storage path. All the datafiles .0...n are stil existing. But when <DB>.ns file not exist, mongo cannot see the database and also collections.

Is there a way to rescue database ? Is there a way to regenerate <DB>.ns file in order to use existing datafiles.

Or any other help?

Comment: Now that's a good question. You don't happen to have any sort of backup, do you? If yes, you could restore with a different dbpath and ***try*** to use the restored .ns file in the original dbpath.

Comment: What version of mongodb are we talking about, btw?

Comment: Hi @MarkusWMahlberg, thanks for your help. Mongo version is 2.6.7. And  we dont have up to date backup, unfortunately

Comment: This is nothing with a short answer. I see some possibilities, but there are too many factors for a quick answer. You might want to contact me (see [my website](myhttp://blog.mahlberg.io)). But honestly, I have just some ideas on what we can try.